# Restraining a widget of my own from assuming any set of sizes in SWT

Tags: java, canvas, widget, swt, windowbuilder

Let's say I have decided to implement my own widget from the base Canvas class in SWT.

I'd like it to have a fixed height of 10 and allow any type of width as long as it conforms to a multiple of 10.

Is there any way to impose this, so the users of my widget will only be allowed to set this kind of values when using my widget in design-mode?

I've tried looking up in `ControlEvent` on `ControlListener`, but it doesn't seem to have a way of canceling a resize.. maybe I have to manually set it back to an acceptable value if I detect a width / height?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to control the layout of your widget. Implement own `Layout` with fixed height and ignore any layout set by user.

Answer (score 0):

When you override `computeSize`, just ignore the width and height hints if they're outside your allowed bounds.  For example:

```
public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed)
{
    int width, height;

    /* We can only be 10px tall */
    height = 10;

    /* Width must be at least 10px */
    if (width < 10)
        width = 10;
    /* Width must be a multiple of 10px */
    else
        width -= (width % 10);

    return new Point(width, height);
}
```